# Combine multiple instances of entry into one, differences into array

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table filled with cars, another table that has the car IDs and the feature IDs and another table with the feature IDs and feature names.

A car can have multiple features in that table. The result of the query is, that i get multiple instances of the same car, each having a different feature.

I would like to have only one instance of the car (by ID) and combine all features into one column (list or array). I could do it in code after the query but i would like to do it in a query instead.

```
Cars table         Car property table      Property table
ID    Name         Car_ID  property_ID     property_id   Property_name
1     Audi         1       1               1             Aircon
2     BMW          1       2               2             Autopilot
3     Mercedes     2       1
                   3       2
```

Result is:

```
1 Audi Aircon
1 Audi Autopilot
2 BMW  Autopilot
3 Mercedes None
```

Result should be:

```
1 Audi [Aircon, Autopilot]
2 BMW   Autopilot
3 Mercedes None
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, no images.) [mcve]

Comment: I added a further explanation, thanks you for the advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @jarlh, could you please elaborate, Im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a basic aggregation query with joins:

```
select c.name, group_concat(Property_name) as properties
from cars c left join
     car_properties cp
     on c.car_id = cp.car_id left join
     properties p
     on p.property_id = cp.property_id
group by c.name
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Does "properties p" stand for the table property or a new col?

Comment: `properties` is the table name.  `p` is a table alias.  I generally pluralize table names, but obviously you should use the actual name in your database.